# How to update Tensorflow on mac?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

> > My current Tensorflow version is 0.10.0. I need to update it to latest version.Latest one is 1.0.0.Is there any method that I can use in
> >     terminal?
>
> This is the python code which I used to find version

```
 import tensorflow as tf;
 print(tf.__version__);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using anaconda;

```
>conda update tensorflow
```

If you are using pip;

```
>pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

If you want to force install a specific version on conda;

```
>conda install tensorflow=1.0.0
```

If you want to force install a specific version on pip;

```
>pip install 'tensorflow==1.0.0' --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check the version using terminal?

Comment: You can use `conda list` (if you are using anaconda) and `pip freeze` or `pip list` (if you are using pip) to see installed packages and their versions.

Comment: I use pip3 on a Mac and I have tensorflow installed but when I upgrade I get this: 

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement tensorflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow
Cleaning up...

Comment: @ethanenglish You may need to upgrade your pip, try this `pip install --upgrade pip`. If you still can not upgrade tensorflow, try a clean install or a virtual environment. Looking at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow), version 1.2.0 is available for macosx. You can try to download and install the appropriate wheel from there as well.

Comment: @umutto That's exactly what I had to do. Apparently I had an old version of pip.

Answer (score 1):

In anaconda cloud, first pick a channel which has the latest version of tensorflow binary. The latest versions are usually available at the channel `conda-forge`

```
conda update -f -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This will upgrade your installation to the very latest version available. As of this writing version `1.4.0-py36_0`