# Error while compiling a model using the adam optimizer in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a ResNet50 model using the Adam optimizer. This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
  cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
  model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
      include_top=True,
      weights=None,
      input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
      classes=100,)

  loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
  model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
  model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

But when I run this it gives the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph execution error:
```

I've tried changing:

```
optimizer="adam"
```

to:

```
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam
```

But I get another error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <class 'keras.optimizers.optimizer_experimental.adam.Adam'>
```

I've searched online but didn't find an answer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should not be from the optimizer. For using `from_logits=True` properly, it is possible to pass `classifier_activation=False` argument to `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` to return the logits of the "top" layer ([TensorFlow documenation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/ResNet50)):

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,
    classifier_activation=None,
)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

Output:

```
782/782 [==============================] - 2259s 3s/step - loss: 4.7819 - accuracy: 0.0762
```

Alternatively, one can use `softmax` as the activation, but with `from_logits=False`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
    classes=100,
    classifier_activation='softmax',
)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

Output:

```
782/782 [==============================] - 2350s 3s/step - loss: 4.7012 - accuracy: 0.0830
```

Comment: Thanks @learner for the answer, however, I copy pasted both samples of your code but they returned the same error.

Comment: @YusufSaad Could you advise on the version of Python and TensorFlow being used? Also, any other information regarding how you run your code (Windows/Linux/..., CPU/GPU, etc.) may help others who may be able to pinpoint the main issue.

Comment: 1. I am on a mac - 
2. I am using python version 3.10.8 - 
3. I am using tensorflow 1.8.0 (I am not sure of this, but this is what I understand from the command I used to install it) - 

pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You may want to try with an upgraded TensorFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504652/how-to-update-tensorflow-on-mac

Comment: my bad, when I ran print(tf.__version__) it came up with 2.11.0. So actually I am using tensorflow version 2.11.0, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I use Python 3.10 and Tensorflow 2.11.0.
Code is working only there is a user warning about loss function

"UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a Softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?
output, from_logits = _get_logits("

Maybe you can try
"loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)"

```
import tensorflow as tf
cifar = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar.load_data()
model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
      include_top=True,
      weights=None,
      input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
      classes=100,)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Did you use Python 3.10 and Tensorflow 2.11.0?

Comment: Yes, when I run python --version, it returns 3.10.8, and print(tf.__version__) return 2.11.0. I am on mac if it makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: It appears the problem is not being generated from the adam optimizer nor from the from_logits. The Traceback says the error is from this line:
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)

Comment: My Python version is 3.10.9

Comment: Maybe you can try "model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50" instead of "model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50"

Comment: It doesn't change anything, also I don't think python 3.10.8 differs a lot from 3.10.9. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you can try 'model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50' instead of 'model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50'